# Creating an instance or object of type IOptionsMonitor. Tried using OptionsMonitor but getting constructor arguments error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to C# and to `IOptionsMonitor` concept

```
MyOptionsClass myOptionObject = new MyOptionClass ();
IOptions<MyOptionsClass> instaceOfIOptions =
    new OptionsWrapper<MyOptionsClass>(myOptionObject );
```

Similar to the approach they have used to get an instance of "IOptions"
I wanted to get of IOptionsMonitor So I tried in similar way but it gives me an compiler error.

```
IOptionsMonitor<CosmosDBOptions> instaceOfIOptionsMonitor =
    new OptionsMonitor<CosmosDBOptions>(myOptionObject);
```

But it asks for 3 arguments (factory, source and cache) in place of `myOptionObject`

what do I need to pass for the arguments here?
How to achieve this?

Comment: Why? What is the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: `IOptions` is usually used with Dependency Injection, why are you trying to construct an `OptionsMonitor` directly? (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

What you need in this case is to implement `IOptionsMonitor<T>`, for example:

```
private sealed class ValueBasedOptionsMonitor<TOptions> : IOptionsMonitor<TOptions>
    where TOptions : class
{
    private TOptions _value;

    public ValueBasedOptionsMonitor(TOptions value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    private event Action<TOptions, string>? OnChangeEvent;

    public TOptions CurrentValue
    {
        get => Get(string.Empty);
        set
        {
            if (_value == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _value = value;
            OnChangeEvent?.Invoke(value, string.Empty);
        }
    }

    public TOptions Get(string name)
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public IDisposable OnChange(Action<TOptions, string> listener)
    {
        OnChangeEvent += listener;
        return Disposable.Create(() => OnChangeEvent -= listener);
    }
}
```

In case if you're not going to modify value, `OnChangeEvent` and `CurrentValue` setter could be omitted, and `OnChange` could be replaced with dummy implementation.

If you need to create `IOptionsMonitor<T>` instance based on the configuration section (I need), use something like this:

```
private sealed class SectionBasedOptionsMonitor<TOptions> : IOptionsMonitor<TOptions>, IDisposable
    where TOptions : class, new()
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IDisposable _changeRegistration;

    private TOptions _options = new();

    public SectionBasedOptionsMonitor(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _changeRegistration = ChangeToken.OnChange(configuration.GetReloadToken, HandleConfigurationChanged);

        UpdateOptions();
    }

    private event Action<TOptions, string>? OnChangeEvent;

    public TOptions CurrentValue => Get(string.Empty);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _changeRegistration.Dispose();
    }

    public TOptions Get(string name)
    {
        // Don't support named options in this case.
        return _options;
    }

    public IDisposable OnChange(Action<TOptions, string> listener)
    {
        OnChangeEvent += listener;
        return Disposable.Create(() => OnChangeEvent -= listener);
    }

    private void UpdateOptions()
    {
        _options = new();
        _configuration.Bind(_options);
    }

    private void HandleConfigurationChanged()
    {
        UpdateOptions();
        OnChangeEvent?.Invoke(_options, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that in this case implementation is disposable, so you'll have to track created instances and dispose them somewhere.